# .Htaccess rewrite URL - Only specific string

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, themes

We have a current issue with a theme and until the developers of this theme fix the issue we need a quick workaround.

What the theme is doing is outputting the wrong URL for images via Amazon

What it is outputting is:

//images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51heut5jiDL.jpg

What it should be is:
https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51heut5jiDL.jpg

What we need to do is change all images outputting

What we don't want is the output already duplicating i.e. https://https:// etc etc as we already have images in place that are using the correct output.

Thanks in advance - hopefully the owners of the theme fix this quickly we just need a workaround and think .htaccess is the best bet.

This is on the wordpress platform - theme is kadence / virtue

Thanks

Comment: Can you add more info regarding the theme which is causing the issue? Is this Wordpress? If you add more tags you will also get more visibility

Comment: Hello, yes its wordpress and its using the virtue theme from kadence